# How can i jump one cshtml page to another cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two .cshmtl pages used for registration. When user completes first registration page I want the controller to jump to another cshtml page without going to controller. How can I complete this task?

```html
<div class="control-group form-actions pull-right">
  <a href="~/Views/Registration/RegStep2" class="btn btn-primary">
    Continue
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

When user click above continue button he will jump on another controller without controller...

Comment: You need to render both the cshtml and hide one in a div .. and show the second one and hide first one on load ... 
(i hope "with going to controller" means post back right?)

Comment: instead of that, can i use partial view for rendering the pages.

Comment: Yes, that is the better way of doing it..

Comment: Please see my below answer for Partial View implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below method using Partial views.

```
<div class="control-group form-actions pull-right">
    <div id="first-div">
        @Html.Partial("PartialView1")
    </div>
    <div id="second-div" style="display:none;">
        @Html.Partial("PartialView2")
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onclickContinue">
        Continue
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onclickContinue(e) {
        $("#first-div").hide();
        $("#second-div").show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this will help me alot